# How to store images in pre-defined sqlite db in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new to android so have very less idea about working of images in sqlite db. I am creating an app in which i will be creating a db with pre-filled data that means i would be putting that data-filled db in assets folder and user will start using it directly once the app is installed.
So i have around 186 images of flags from different countries, which i need to show in a custom listview. Can you tell me how to store all images in sqlite db and get it back to show on listview?
I tried using some IDE for inserting images in db but their decoding doesn't work.
Please help!!!

Comment: Store only the Id's(give each image a unique id) of the files in the database - and retrieve the id'sand search for it in the assets folder since you are already putting images in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this First of all you have to store all images in blob datatype into sqlite database then    for retrieving from database user following code

```
query_compnay_id="Select * From "+mStaticValues.company_master;
mCursor_company_detail=mDatabaseConnectionAPI.ExecuteQueryGetCursor((query_compnay_id));
mCursor_company_detail.moveToFirst();
byte[] by =mCursor_company_detail.getBlob(mCursor_company_detail.getColumnIndex(mStaticValues.image_data));
mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(by, 0, by.length, null);
```